# import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am using python 3.8.5 and running on Windows 10. I tried to insert a plot in Tkinter Gui, but when I import `matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg`, it raises the error shown below. Mathplotlib and Tkinter versions are the latest versions 8.6 and 3.3.1, respectively. And I also installed the "Pillow" module.

[image showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4xO0.png)

```
>>>import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg
```

Here also is the error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _backend_tk
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 15, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backend_bases import (
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 45, in <module>
    from matplotlib import (
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 27, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Comment: Is Pillow installed? If no, install it with "pip install Pillow" and check if you still get the error.

Comment: @P.Leibner Pillow is already installed. I wrote it on post. Even if I installed Pillow, it does not work.

Comment: Maybe your using the wrong version of python as your interpreter?

Comment: no, i installed only one python version and I don't even use virtual environment to run this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda try

`conda install pillow`

if you are using pip try:

`pip install Pillow`

Make sure you are installing to the right environment. The import should then work.

Comment: can you import pillow by itself?

Comment: how? I install using "py -m pip install pillow" command. But it does not work still get error.

Comment: Try a script where you do `from PIL import Image`